# How to use custom fields like Title to show value in content?

Tags: custom-field, automation

I need some automation in my Wordpress Blog.

As we type Title and it appears in post. How can we add fields like Title?

Then how I can show the value of those fields in my single-post. I want to use few placeholders to be replaced with values of my custom fields.

For example:

Field1: My Car
Field2: My Watch

{Placeholder1} and {placeholder2} should be replaced with values My and My Watch.

Thanks in advance, plz guide me.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to save your custom fields as `postmeta`. Normally `metabox`es appear in the sidebar instead of within the post itself in the Editor, so that's one difference you'll face.

Once your data is saved, you will also need to create a template to display that data. Themes don't search for and display `postmeta` by default, so you'll want to first create a child theme by setting up a folder with a `style.css` file containing a few comments that tell WP your child theme's name and what its parent theme is. Then, you can copy the parent theme's single post file - likely `single.php` but could be various others depending on how your theme is coded - into your child theme. Finally, wherever in that file you want your custom data to appear, such as between `the_title()` and `the_content()`, you can get the `postmeta` and output each field wrapped in whatever HTML you want.

Comment: my theme uses this code to show app version $version = get_datos_info('version'); how can I and replace it with my content?